# Alias to twisted server content?

Tags: web-server, redirect, httpd, alias

I have buildbot, using twisted, configured to run on port 8010.

If I navigate to `http://mysite.com:8010` I can access everything just fine. However, I want people to see the page at `http://mysite.com/build`

Right now I redirect, but I'd prefer to somehow alias it but I don't know how to do that with a port (I know how to remap to a different directory, but not to a port on the machine).

**I'm going to open a more specific question in a new thread**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've configured a Buildbot instance, but glancing through the master.cfg that is created, I noticed this line:

```
c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8010))
```

Notice that the port is explicitly set to port 8010.  You can change this to be port 80, which is the default http port.  You'd have to then run your buildbot as root or use some other mechanism for handling accessing the privileged port.  Stop by #buildbot on irc.freenode.net and they could give you some more specific guidance.

I hope that gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: I'm also running httpd so 80 is taken and I don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

Assumming a Linux system, have you thought of using iptables to reroute port 80 requests to 8010?

I used this technique when I wanted to secure a tomcat/java application that ran as root and used port 80.  As port 80 attachment is restricted to root, I ran the tomcat/java app as port 8080 and setup iptables to redirect port 80 requests to port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite with mod_proxy on apache or something else like that, I'm using nginx proxy module. You just need to make sure that the links on the pages point to correct places when accessed via such rewrite.

This allows you to build the website from smaller pieces, some handled in separate processes. It also gives flexibility as those rewrites are easy change when needed.

Comment: Will I be able to install mod_xxx when I don't have root? Do you have a link to an example of how to do this - sorry I'm very new to web admin.

Comment: Only, if also apache is installed non-root.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know anything about buildbot, but web content is web content.  Why not set up regular Apache with `DocumentRoot` pointing to whatever mysite.com:8010 is server.  One content getting out two doors using two different servers?

Comment: My other problem is that I'm going to be running more that one twisted server each on a new port. Would this solution work for that situation?

Comment: There is no limit on how many times one content can be served out.  There is however a limit of one daemon listening to one (or more) ports and not sharing them with any other daemons.