# How do I serve content from multiple web servers (appache, twisted) all through port 80?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, twisted

My question relates to my [previous](https://serverfault.com/questions/46309/alias-to-twisted-server-content) question but I realized that my previous question was off the mark.

I'm using a hosting service so I don't have access to root (just a user account) and my Apache web server is a Virtual Host running on port 80. The DocumentRoot is **http://build.website.org** and is at **/home/*myname*/build.website.org/** on the file system.

I want to run multiple buildbot masters and display build results for the projects *project1*, *project2* etc. at **http://build.website.org/project1/**, **http://build.website.org/project2/** etc.

I set up my first buildbot master with the twisted web server on port 8010 and can access the content by going to **http://build.website.org:8010** but I can't figure out how to make the content on **http://build.website.org:8010** visible at **http://build.website.org/project1/**

So, I want to know if it makes sense to have a unique twisted server for each master? And, how I should make **http://build.website.org:801N** visible at **http://build.website.org/projectN/** (if this is the correct way to go about doing this)?

Sorry, I'm very new to web admin issues and need very detailed help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in Apache through reverse proxying. See http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies for setup information. Feel free to post again if you have more questions.